# R loading multiple excel files and merge

Tags: r, loops, merge, excel-2007, lapply

I have many excel files that I need to load and merge into a single data frame.

The script below works! However, before merging all files I want to paste each file name in a new column.

```
library(gdata)
library(tools)
filelist <- list.files(pattern = "*\\.xlsx$")
files = lapply(filelist, read.xls, header=TRUE)

new = Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=T), files)
```

So I added this:

```
files$source <- file_path_sans_ext(filelist)
```

However, this didn't work.

My desired output is:

```
Col1 Col2 Col3 Source(this column doesnt exist in excel)
abc  1    2    Filename1
def  3    4    Filename2
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
library(tools)
source <- file_path_sans_ext(filelist)
files1 <- Map(cbind, files, Source=source)
files1
#[[1]]
#  Col1      Col2   Source
#1    A 0.5365853 Filname1
#2    A 0.4196231 Filname1

#[[2]]
# Col1     Col2   Source
#1    A 0.847460 Filname2
#2    C 0.266022 Filname2

#[[3]]
# Col1       Col2   Source
#1    C -0.4664951 Filname3
#2    C -0.8483700 Filname3
```

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
files <- lapply(1:3, function(i) data.frame(Col1=sample(LETTERS[1:3], 2, 
         replace=TRUE), Col2=rnorm(2)))
 filelist <- paste0('Filname', 1:3, '.txt')
```

Comment: I also tried this one and got an error Error in dots[[2L]][[1L]] : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable...not sure what I did wrong. Much appreciated your help. Peddie

Comment: @PeddiePooh On a example data I created it worked.  So, without an example, it is hard to know what might be the problem.

Comment: @PeddiePooh Just to reproduce that my code would work, I added some example

Comment: @akun I managed to pass the source file as a new column using files$source <- file_path_sans_ext(filelist) however it only paste one value (suspect to be either first in array or last Im not sure) for all rows which are wrong. For example there are 342 rows for each file so the first 342 rows should say "April 2014", then row 343 should be "May 2014" and so on but its all April 2014 in the whole list :( Apologies if i dont use the right term.

Comment: @PeddiePooh  Your `files` is a list, which can be accessed with a `for` loop for `lapply/Map` solutions.  Please look at my example and the code carefullly.

Answer (score 1):

Or loop solution passing the name of the source file to a data frame that constitutes the data set that you want to merge.

```
for (i in length(files)) {
    dta <- files[[i]]
    dta$source <- filelist[[i]]
    files[[i]] <- dta
}
```

I broke it down into chunks as what you initially suggested:

```
files$source <- file_path_sans_ext(filelist)
```

would pass the whole vector to the `$source` column.

Comment: Hello Konrad, I tried this but I got an error message Error in filelist[[i]] : subscript out of bounds - any ideas? Much appreciated - Peddie

Comment: It would appear that your vector with the file names has more elements that the list of data sets. You can see what happens if you use `length(filelist)` but on principle you would expect for the both objects to have corresponding number of elements.

Comment: Im pretty new so excuse my ignorance here. I only have 11 files at the moment but expect to grow. So I only wrote for the list to look at file pattern XLSX. When I use length(filelist) it returns 12. Do you know why that is?

Comment: I would expect that the filter is finding another file (temporary, hidden?). It's difficult to speculate without a reproducible example.

Comment: I eventually got there and I thought this was correct however when I checked the data the only last file of the array was filled in the source column (this case is september, and the rest of the rows appear as NA). Any ideas what I did wrong? Thank you - Peddie